# How to extract results from safely in purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

## Data

Following is example data set:

```
> dput(veh)
structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("857-850", "857-850", "857-850", 
"857-850"), svel = c(12.21277, 12.22125, 12.2362, 12.26268), 
    frspacing = c(10.73435, 10.64279, 10.54999, 10.45493), Local.Y = c(394.76339, 
    395.98552, 397.20914, 398.43541), PrecVehLocalY = c(409.70444, 
    410.83501, 411.96583, 413.09704), CC0 = c(4.1374232, 4.1374232, 
    4.1374232, 4.1374232), CC8 = c(1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75), CC9 = c(1.04, 
    1.04, 1.04, 1.04), PrecVehLength = c(4.2067, 4.2067, 4.2067, 
    4.2067)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", "svel", "frspacing", 
"Local.Y", "PrecVehLocalY", "CC0", "CC8", "CC9", "PrecVehLength"
), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

## What I want to do:

I am applying the following function to the data frame `veh`:

```
apply_W99 <- function(df){
  for( i in ( seq_len( nrow(df)-1 ) + 1 ) ) {
    if( i <= 2L ) {
      df$Un_dt_1[i] <- df$svel[i-1] * 3.6 + 
        3.6 * ( df$CC8[i] + ( df$CC8[i] - df$CC9[i] ) * 
                  df$svel[i-1] * 3.6 / 80 ) * 0.1
      df$Un_dt_2[i] <- 3.6 * ( df$frspacing[i-1] - df$CC0[i] ) / 0.1
    } else {
      df$Un_dt_1[i] <- df$Un_dt[i-1] + 
        3.6 * ( df$CC8[i] + ( df$CC8[i] - df$CC9[i] ) * 
                  df$Un_dt[i-1] / 80 ) * 0.1
      df$Un_dt_2[i] <- 3.6 * ( df$pred_frspacing[i-1] - df$CC0[i] ) / 0.1
    }
    df$Un_dt[i] <- pmin( df$Un_dt_1[i], df$Un_dt_2[i] )
    if( i <= 2 ) {
      df$pred_Local.Y[i] <- df$Local.Y[i-1] + 
        0.5 * ( ( df$Un_dt[i] + df$svel[i-1] ) / 3.6 ) * 0.1
    } else {
      df$pred_Local.Y[i] <- df$pred_Local.Y[i-1] + 
        0.5 * ( ( df$Un_dt[i] + df$Un_dt[i-1] ) / 3.6 ) * 0.1
    }

    df$pred_frspacing[i] <- df$PrecVehLocalY[i] - df$pred_Local.Y[i] - df$PrecVehLength[i]
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Note that original data frame has multiple `Vehicle.ID2`s. I used `tidyr` and `purrr` to apply this function. Also, I am using the function `safely` in `purrr` to collect both the results and the errors.

```
library(tidyr)
foob <- veh %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID2) %>% 
  nest()

library(purrr)
foos <- foob %>% 
  mutate(joo = map(data, safely(apply_W99)))
```

This works fine. Now, I want to get the results. `safely` creates a list with `result` and `error`. For the example data:

```
> dput(foos$joo)
list(structure(list(result = structure(list(svel = c(12.21277, 
12.22125, 12.2362, 12.26268), frspacing = c(10.73435, 10.64279, 
10.54999, 10.45493), Local.Y = c(394.76339, 395.98552, 397.20914, 
398.43541), PrecVehLocalY = c(409.70444, 410.83501, 411.96583, 
413.09704), CC0 = c(4.1374232, 4.1374232, 4.1374232, 4.1374232
), CC8 = c(1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75), CC9 = c(1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 
1.04), PrecVehLength = c(4.2067, 4.2067, 4.2067, 4.2067), Un_dt_1 = c(NA, 
44.73644328054, 45.5093762168213, 46.2847786738341), Un_dt_2 = c(NA, 
237.489364799999, 249.715278159729, 245.301888411047), Un_dt = c(NA, 
44.73644328054, 45.5093762168213, 46.2847786738341), pred_Local.Y = c(NA, 
395.554351295563, 396.807765455249, 398.082684273174), pred_frspacing = c(NA, 
11.0739587044369, 10.9513645447513, 10.8076557268256)), .Names = c("svel", 
"frspacing", "Local.Y", "PrecVehLocalY", "CC0", "CC8", "CC9", 
"PrecVehLength", "Un_dt_1", "Un_dt_2", "Un_dt", "pred_Local.Y", 
"pred_frspacing"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame")), error = NULL), .Names = c("result", "error")))
```

How can I get only the `result` part as a new data frame?
I tried using `foos <- unnest(foos, map(joo, transpose()))` but that didn't work.

Comment: You could just index it, assuming you know where it is: `foos$joo[[1]]$result`

Comment: @alistaire, That's a good suggestion and I did try it. But when `result` is `NULL`, it throws an error because `NULL` is not a data frame.

Comment: I guess you could `purrr`ify it: `foos %>% select(joo) %>% as.list() %>% map(1) %>% map_df('result')`. Honestly, I'd clean up the function first, so you don't have errors to deal with.

Comment: @alistaire, Using `map(1)` reduces the output to the first `Vehicle.ID2`. It works for the example data. But for the full data set, with multiple `Vehicle.ID2`, there are some results which are `NULL` because of the data. I want to keep all the non-`NULL` results in one data frame with there corresponding `Vehicle.ID2`s. Using `unnest` is unsuccessful because `joo` is a list of 2.

Comment: `map_if(~!is.null(.x), 1)` or similar? You really need to provide relevantly similar sample data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

per purrr tutorial from here (https://www.rstudio.com/conference/) try

```
 transpose(x)[["result"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say `list.out` is the list output you created. If you want to extract the result components from this list, you can do the following.

```r
list.out %>%
 purrr::map("result") %>%  # Extract results 
 purrr::compact() %>% # Keep the elements of interest 
 purrr::reduce(bind_rows) # in case, if you want to combine the results as a dataframe; this assumes that the output of the function is in a dataframe.
```

Note that `map("result")` is equivalent to `map(function(x) x[["result"]])`. So, the logic is same as what others have already suggested but the syntax is simpler.